# find all youtube links with js (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say there is a div that has content and a youtube link.  I want to grab that youtube link and embed it.

```
<div id="content"><p>Here is a cool video.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0</p></div>
```

I want to grab the link and replace it with the embed code with js (jquery).

Update 1:

This is my js so far:

```
    $("#content").each(function(){
    var allContent = $(this).html();
    //need regex to find all links with youtube in it, ovbiously it can't == youtube.com, but basically the link has to have youtube.com in it.
    if ($("a",allContent).attr("href") == "youtube.com" ) {
        // grab youtube video id
        /* replace link with <div id="yt-video">
        <object width="560" height="340"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/429l13dS6kQ&hl=en&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/429l13dS6kQ&hl=en&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed></object>
        </div>
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer the this question might help with the regex part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713222/add-class-to-all-links-that-link-to-a-certain-domain-with-js-jquery

Comment: BTW there's a YouTube javascript API that's reasonably easy to use and fairly powerful (playlists etc) https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I changed the `content` from an id to a class because I was guessing you'd have more than one content area?

I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to do this, but this is my attempt at it. *Note* I suck at regex, so what I have is as close as I can get, I'm sure someone can help improve it, so it doesn't have to replace the `?v=` inside the each loop.

HTML

```
<div class="content"><p>Here is a cool video.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0 and this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLBPsZVI8Gc&feature=player_embedded</p></div>
<div class="content"><p>Here is a cool video.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLBPsZVI8Gc&feature=player_embedded</p></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // I added the video size here in case you wanted to modify it more easily
 var vidWidth = 425;
 var vidHeight = 344;

 $('.content:contains("youtube.com/watch")').each(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  var txt = $(this).html();
  // Tthis could be done by creating an object, adding attributes & inserting parameters, but this is quicker
  var e1 = '<obj'+'ect width="' + vidWidth + '" height="' + vidHeight + '"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/';
  var e2 = '&hl=en&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" ' +
   'value="always"></param><em'+'bed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/';
  var e3 = '&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' + vidWidth +
   '" ' + 'height="' + vidHeight + '"></embed></object> ';

  var vid = txt.match(/((\?v=)(\w[\w|-]*))/g); // end up with ?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
  if (vid.length) {
   $.each(vid, function(i){
    var ytid = this.replace(/\?v=/,'') // end up with oHg5SJYRHA0
    that.append( e1 + ytid + e2 + ytid + e3 ) 
   })
  }
 })
})
```

I'll be the first to admit it's not pretty, but it works. I also pasted a working version of this code in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.me/8e894ba98a9e1999a2854d81b1b827da)

---

Update: I've cleaned up the code a bit, here is how it looks now ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9r7pj/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // I added the video size here in case you wanted to modify it more easily
 var vidWidth = 425;
 var vidHeight = 344;

 var obj = '<object width="' + vidWidth + '" height="' + vidHeight + '">' +
     '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/[vid]&hl=en&fs=1">' +
     '</param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param ' +
     'name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><em' +
     'bed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/[vid]&hl=en&fs=1" ' +
     'type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" ' +
     'allowfullscreen="true" width="' + vidWidth + '" ' + 'height="' +
     vidHeight + '"></embed></object> ';

 $('.content:contains("youtube.com/watch")').each(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  var vid = that.html().match(/(?:v=)([\w\-]+)/g); // end up with v=oHg5SJYRHA0
  if (vid.length) {
   $.each(vid, function(){
    that.append( obj.replace(/\[vid\]/g, this.replace('v=','')) );
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Good answer, only change is in my answer below

Comment: hi, I want also to remove the youtube link and replace it by the video , how can I do that ?

Comment: @Waseem: I updated the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/9r7pj/20/), but I still suck at regex. I added this line `that.html(function(i,h){return h.replace(/(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=\w+((\&\w+=\w+)+)?)/g,'');});` and I tested the regex (http://rubular.com/r/QiOvgv8stR) and it seemed to work there, but not in jsFiddle... so I have no idea. Either way, you can manually remove the extra parameters from the url if you have to.

Comment: @fudgey
  I modified the regex and it worked fine , check it in jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9r7pj/21/

Comment: @Waseem: I just noticed that youtube provides iframe code by default now. I guess so it'll work with iphones or something. Just a heads up ;)

Answer (score 3):

I was on pretty much the same track as fudgey, but I suck a regexps even more than him, so I've "borrowed" his code up until that point. One change I have made is to use swfobject to embed the video rather than handrolling the embed code. It just means you have to add the swfobject library to the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
```

HTML is the same as fudgey's

```
<div class="content"><p>Here is a cool video.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0 and this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLBPsZVI8Gc&feature=player_embedded</p></div>
<div class="content"><p>Here is a cool video.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLBPsZVI8Gc&feature=player_embedded</p></div>
```

Small change to the javascript

```
$(function(){
    // I added the video size here in case you wanted to modify it more easily
    var vidWidth = 425;
    var vidHeight = 344;

    $('.content:contains("youtube.com/watch")').each(function(i){
        var that = $(this);
        var txt = $(this).html();       
        var vid = txt.match(/((\?v=)(\w[\w|-]*))/g); // end up with ?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
            if (vid.length) {
                $.each(vid, function(x){
                    var ytid = this.replace(/\?v=/,'') // end up with oHg5SJYRHA0   
                    var playerid = 'videoplayer_' + i + "_" + x; 
                    that.append("<div id='" + playerid + "'></div>");
                    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + ytid, playerid, vidWidth, vidHeight, "8");                     
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

Kudos to Fudgey's answer tho

Comment: Nice! I forgot about using swfobject.js :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the content of the div with something like this:

```
var text = $("div#content p").html();  // or .text()
```

With that text, you can use string manipulation or regular expressions to find the url.
Then, you can create jquery content to add with:

```
var content = $('<a href="...">...</a>');
```

and add it to something with the manipulation methods of jquery, like

```
var destination = $("body");
destination.append(content);
```

To get more detail than that, your question will need more details.

Comment: I've updated my question with my current js.  I added comments to what I need or what I'm stuck on.