# add class to all links that link to a certain domain with js (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a bunch of links like this:

```
<a href="foo.com">blah</a> and this <a href="example.com">one</a> and here is another <a href="foo.com"></a>.
```

How would I add a class to all the links that link to foo.com?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to make sure you get http://foo.com, http://bar.foo.com/about, and not http://bazfoo.com, try:

```
$("a[href*='/foo.com'], a[href*='.foo.com']").addClass('your_class');
```

Here's a stronger solution with regular expressions, this is probably slower, mind you, but checks the domain is on the start:

```
$("a").filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).attr('href')
                      .match(/^https?:\/\/([^/]*\.)?foo\.com(\/.*|$)/i);
    })
    .addClass('your_class');
```

Here are some test cases: http://jsbin.com/oruhu
(you can edit it here: http://jsbin.com/oruhu/edit ).

Comment: This is pretty much ideal! I would possibly replace the `*` selectors with `+` to make the expression more efficient and not match stuff like http://.foo.com

Answer (score 3):

If you have links to distinct pages on the foo domain like:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/eggs.html">
<a href="http://foo.com/bacon.html">
```

then you can use a selector like this:

```
$("a[href^=http://foo.com/]").addClass("newClass")
```

which will find all links that start with "http://foo.com/"
or

```
$("a[href*=/foo.com/]").addClass("newClass")
```

which will find all links that contain "/foo.com/"

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href='foo.com']").addClass('your_class')
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivially:
`$("a[href='http://foo.com']").addClass('foo');`
But that assumes an exact match on the URL.