# Add class to href by jquery

Tags: jquery, class

Following this post: [add class to all links that link to a certain domain with js (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713222/add-class-to-all-links-that-link-to-a-certain-domain-with-js-jquery)

I attempted to add a class to hyperlinks with jquery, but it is causing me hell. I am developing a site locally which I added this code to (as well as having jquery linked to):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href*='gallery']").addClass('thumb');
</script>
```

with no effect on my links. I decided to strip down the page to the barest bones, see if I could identify the problem. Still no effect. As soon as I place it online, it works:

http://www.anunexpectacle.com/files/test.html

Is there something about local dev that would stop this? Why am I unable to give my links a class by jquery? Please help!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the code inside a document.ready function so it waits for the dom to load up

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

or shortform

```
$(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Also make sure you are importing the jQuery library into your project

ex.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user77510 Your welcome.  Don't forget to click the green checkmark if this answered your question

Comment: yes. it was sort of unclear for me though, because things were working and not, unexpectedly, here and there. I thanked because it was useful advice, but I'm not sure it fixed my problem: I'm agnostic on this point. A green tick nevertheless.