# Add external class to links not on domain OR subdomain

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add an external class to links that are not on our domain...easy to find a solution but it doesn't catch subdomains.

So, how can I use addClass("external") on  tags only where the href hostlocation DOESN'T contain 'hw.ac.uk'?

Following is popular but doesn't catch subdomains (of which ours can be one or two deep, e.g., subdomain., www.subdomain., etc.)

```
$("a").filter(function() {
return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).addClass('external');
```

I guess I want the opposite of [add class to all links that link to a certain domain with js (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713222/add-class-to-all-links-that-link-to-a-certain-domain-with-js-jquery)

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score -1):

```
// Creating custom :external selector
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
            && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
};

// Add 'external' CSS class to all external links
$('a:external').addClass('external');
```

**EDIT**
Didn't catch the subdomain issue. Tha above code only take into concern the top domain