# contenteditable realtime replace youtube url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

so the problem is, i have a contenteditable div, with a keyup function binded. 
everytime somebody puts a youtube url in it, it has to be replaced by an embedded movie.

i came up with a regex like this :

```
content.match(/http:\/\/\w{0,3}.?youtube+\.\w{2,3}\/watch\?v=.*?(?=\s)/g);
```

firefox wil do the replace after a whitespace, but in ie it won't work.

any suggestions?
thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best at regex, but I did post an answer a while back about [replacing youtube url text with the embeded player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712847/find-all-youtube-links-with-js-jquery/1713320#1713320). Maybe it'll help?