# Wordpress/Custom field Youtube / I want to replace video url (watch?v= with /v/) with php

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, field

I want to replace in post and archive custom field the youtube url with php.

- From: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKAjQfL31Dw To:
- http://www.youtube.com/v/FKAjQfL31Dw

My code is:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ixosrip', true) ) { ?>
<embed style="width:150px;height:25px;" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "ixosrip", $single = true); ?>&amp;ap=%2526fmt%3D18&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;color1=0xC0C0C0&amp;color2=0xFFFFFF&amp;border=0&amp;loop=0">
<?php } else { ?>
<em>No sound</em>
<?php } ?>
```

Current i use a javascript, taked from here: [find all youtube links with js (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712847/find-all-youtube-links-with-js-jquery/1713320#1713320) / But its loads very slow my site.
Is there any way to do this with php in the custom field?

Thank you.
David.

Answer (score 0):

If you can iterate over your custom fields, just do it with a simple PHP `str_replace`:

```
$new_url = str_replace('/watch?v=', '/v/', $old_url);
```

Where `$old_url` is your video's current slug.

UPDATED ANSWER: You could parse the URL, grabbing the `v` component:

```
parse_str($video_url, $params);
$video_id = $params['v'];
$video_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$video_id;
```

You would put this in your loop or your post page template or whatever, where `$video_url` is the field containing, well, the YouTube video URL you want to alter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment martin. The problem is that i dont know how do i insert your code to this:
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "ixosrip", $single = true); ?>

Comment: Just an edge case, but any YouTube URLs with further GET variables, for things like closed captions, etc. this will break.

Comment: Indeed, Lucanos. I've updated my answer with an alternative method.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just execute a SQL update on the db? Why do you want to do it with PHP?

Comment: Hello, 
At first i would like to thank you all for your responds.

Now to the point:
I try to put the new code of Martin to post template for testing inside the loop like:
<?php 
parse_str($video_url, $params);
$video_id = $params['v'];
$video_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$video_id;
 ?> 
After i update my post but i do not see the desired result. Do i something wrong?
@Jorbi:
Via Sql i must do that every time or? That needs every day update cause i upload every day minimum 25 videos to Youtube and embed in my site via custom field.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It would be easier for you to research the various techniques and function names given, rather than wait hand-on-foot for some one to write the solution for you. Who knows? You may even learn something along the way...

Answer (score 0):

Aye there,
One thing I can think of is making 2 custom fields where one would be the id and would have a value like 'FKAjQfL31Dw'

...and the other would have a value of either 'v/' or 'watch?v=' depending on which one u choose. (can be done via radio buttons)

so ur code might look something like

```
  <embed style="width:150px;height:25px;" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/
    <?php $key='youtube_format'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
    <?php $key='youtube_id'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
&amp;ap=%2526fmt%3D18&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;color1=0xC0C0C0&amp;color2=0xFFFFFF&amp;border=0&amp;loop=0">
```

If your trying to do this in archives, you would most likely add this code to content.php or content-video.php.